# How do you get the IG-88 hat? *spoiler*

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2013

IG-88 was one of the bounty hunters Vader asks to hunt down Han Solo in Star Wars Episode V.

[image]

So what does that have to do with this hat?

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As we all know, Fett gets the bounty for finding Han Solo.

http://thestarwarssaga.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/EP5-KEY-350_R.jpg

But here is how you do it, IG-88 style

> Answer a bountied question, but the bounty goes to *another* answer or expires without being awarded.

Comment: Ok, let me challege you. How can these two users get IG-88 without answering any bounty questions? http://stackoverflow.com/users/1367646  http://stackoverflow.com/users/2522603

Comment: Though 23/25  sampling users who got the bounty satisfy the first part of your criteria, but there are 2 of them does get the bounty themselves. (The answer themselves need to be post in the bounty period though)

Comment: @hwlau: is it possible they answered now-deleted bountied questions?

Comment: @Marti Seems plausible, but I think they need at least one vote. It is hard to thing that they want to delete it

Comment: @hwlau: both users posted an answer on a question with a bounty that subsequently expired during the Winterbash. Look at their most recent answers, then check the question edit history.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I forget the bounty rule. I was thinking all of them have to reward at least half of the bounty to one of the person, but the is additional criteria

Comment: Auto-awarding only works for answers posted after the bounty was started and only if scoring 2 or more.

Comment: Also, I think your answer score can't be negative.

Comment: This answer makes sense, I was surprised today with an IG-88 hat and I was looking for the reason. I fit in the described scenario.